# NamedQueries WHERE EQUALS statement in JPA REST

Tags: sql, rest, jpa, jax-rs

I'm creating a REST service, it was simple at first, but now I want to get table rows with a specific value in a column.

This is an example of the NamedQueries I have now:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "ExampleTable.findAll", query = "SELECT e FROM ExampleTable e"),
@NamedQuery(name = "ExampleTable.findById", query = "SELECT e FROM ExampleTable e WHERE e.id = :id"),
@NamedQuery(name = "ExampleTable.findByAmlClientCategory", query = "SELECT e FROM ExampleTable e WHERE e.amlClientCategory = :amlClientCategory"),
@NamedQuery(name = "ExampleTable.findByClientId", query = "SELECT e FROM ExampleTable e WHERE e.clientId = :clientId")
```

Now if I want to find by specific AmlClientCategory value instead, lets say all the rows which contain a "1" in the AmlClientCategory column, how do I do that?

I'm following [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html) guide to create my REST service.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: You work in JPA with entities, not with SQL tables. Is `e.amlClientCategory` an entity or a string?

Comment: @Andreil It's an Entity I think, I have a (a)Entity above them all

Comment: I dont think so. it should be a String always.

Comment: "an internal server error" ... ok, and don't you think people may need to see what this error/exception is? What about providing the entity class too, since all JPQL queries refer to fields of the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute it like this (assuming AmlClientCategory is a string):

```
List<ExampleTable> results = em.createNamedQuery("ExampleTable.findByAmlClientCategory", ExampleTable.class)
    .setParameter("AmlClientCategory", "1")
    .getResultList();
```

Comment: @Somethingcool123 Correct, you can place this in the Facade class

Answer (score 1):

Use below code in your DAO implementation class.

```
Query query= entityManager.createNamedQuery("ExampleTable.findByAmlClientCategory");
query.setParameter("AmlClientCategory", "1");
Collection result = query.getResultList();
```

Here you can set multiple arguments for your `NamedQuery`.